# do happen, do believe and etc. When they are used?

Tags: grammar

I sometimes read or hear English native speaker say or write:

> ... do happen ...

or

> ... do believe...

or

> .. do love...

and so on.

My question is when should I use `do` + `verb`? Why not only use `verb` such as `believe` or `love`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use do before a verb to lay emphasis on that verb as in the case when somebody asks you a question. For example your friend asks you whether you like that food or not. And you reply emphatically positive by saying:

Yes I do like it.

Answer (score 1):

The emphatic "do" is used when the speaker is contradicting what the listen believes (or what the speaker thinks the listener believes).

> —I heard you don't eat meat.
>   — I do eat meat, but I'm trying to eat less.
>
> — I think you are an atheist.
>   — I do believe in god, but not as a person.
>
> I do love pizza!

In the last case it implies that the speaker thinks that the listener doesn't know how much he loves pizza.