# Differences between I do remember and I remember

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, british-english

Can anybode help me with these sentences?

Time is running nowhere. **I do remember** clearly this day

*and*

Time is running nowhere. **I remember clearly** this day.

***Or***

**It does frightens** most of time cause we are not used to it.

*and*

**It frightens most** of time cause we are not used to it.

I don't understand why we use auxiliary verb here??? I mean  **'do'** and how it's changed these senteces ???

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/203795/do-happen-do-believe-and-etc-when-they-are-used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples don't seem to require "do" or "does".

We would normally only include "do" or "does" either to *confirm*, *contradict* or *contrast* a previous question or statement.

For example:

> Q. Do you remember that day?
> A. I do remember that day.

> I don't remember much from last year but I do remember that day.